# How to get values from repeated JSON keys iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have an app that gathers a users data via JSON. After putting the data into an array, I want to get how many different values occur for a certain key, not how many times is appears.

Example.

I gather restaurant data the user has assembled on a site. His JSON data spits out a key for genre: 6 Pizza places, 4 Chinese places, and 2 Mexican places that he has "liked". So there are 3 different values for the genre key, but they occur x amount of times. I want to be able to see how many different values for genre there are, not how many times they occur, which can get via NSCountedSet once I get the values for genre.

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to do this without hard coding in every possibility.

Thanks!

Comment: *Please* go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes.  Then you will understand that you had an array of JSON "objects" (equivalent to dictionaries).  It's a simple matter to iterate through the array and access the individual dictionaries, once you understand the structure.

Comment: I understand that. I just didn't know how to get a single string for a key that is repeated x times. If I was going to place it into a table view, I didn't want "Pizza" to appear 6 times.

Comment: That question has nothing to do with JSON -- it's simply a matter of "de-duping" a list.

Comment: It was just an example and a situation that I am currently in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a format like:

```
 [
  {
  "Restaurant":"McDonalds",
  "Genre":"Vomit"
  },
  {
  "Restaurant":"Wendys",
  "Genre":"Gross"
  },
  {
  "Restaurant":"Chipotle",
  "Genre":"Delish"
  },
  {
  "Restaurant":"White Castle",
  "Genre":"Gross"
  }
 ]
```

You could do the following:

```
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonInDataForm options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSMutableArray *types = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(NSDictionary *restaurant in jsonArray)
{
    if(![types containsObject:[restaurant objectForKey:@"Genre"]])
        [types addObject:[restaurant objectForKey:@"Genre"]];
}

int numberOfGenres = [types count];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, poorly worded question. I  forgot to add that I want to put the Genres into a table view. So there would be 3 cells, each one with an NSString of the Genre. How would I get the strings of Genre though with out getting 2 copies of "Gross"?